# XML Sorting when nodes field value exists

Tags: xml, xslt-grouping

please help me with below scenario
XML Input:

```
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-05-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-06-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-02-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-03-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
</EmploymentUpdateRequests>
```

This needs to be sorted for the all the same Employment number , child node FORNAMN/ValidFrom date value in ascending order. When there is FORNAMN is not null. If it is null then move all those nodes to bottom of the output and do not sort.
Expected output:

```
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-02-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-03-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-01-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
    <FieldValue Name="FORNAMN" Type="String">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-05-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-06-13</ValidUntil>
      <Value>Bianca</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
<EmploymentUpdateRequest>
  <CompanyNo>0070</CompanyNo>
  <EmploymentNo>982116</EmploymentNo>
  <Fields>
    <FieldValue Name="EmpFrom" Type="Date">
      <ValidFrom Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-14</ValidFrom>
      <ValidUntil Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2099-12-31</ValidUntil>
      <Value Format="yyyy-MM-dd">2017-04-14</Value>
    </FieldValue>
  </Fields>
</EmploymentUpdateRequest>
</EmploymentUpdateRequests>
```

Comment: What would you like to use,  `php` or something else? What method  did you try? Please provide the `code` you have and answer my questions.. Thank you..

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"><xsl:template match="/"<xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template><xsl:template match="EmploymentUpdateRequests"><xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="EmploymentUpdateRequest" group-by="descendant::FieldValue[@Name ='FORNAMN']"><xsl:sort select="descendant::FieldValue[@Name ='FORNAMN']/ValidFrom" order="ascending"/><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></xsl:for-each-group> </xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @ jagb : sorry for the dirty format. it didnt allow me for the space issue.